# apt-get command not found in kali linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I just tried to update using `apt-get` command and it shows

```
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

And my **sources.list** is always empty although i add the repositories.

I use **Kali Linux**

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I guess I'm too late, but why would Kali not ship with apt? Or was removed afterwards?

Comment: @Braiam It appears the OP ditched it by mistake, see this question in meta: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4657/systematically-closing-kali-questions

Comment: @dr01 I'm pretty sure `apt` is in the `essential` segment of both debian and Kali, so they would have had to consciously and deliberately disable multiple safeguards specifically designed to prevent such "mistakes"...

Comment: @Shadur And are you surprised by so? ;)

Comment: No. Because Kal

Comment: "I use Kali Linux and I have no idea what to do" pretty much sums up so many of these questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest version of Kali Linux is based on Debian testing.  On Kali rolling the apt version is 1.6~alpha3. Go to the [Debian -- package search results -- apt](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=apt&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) webpage and manually download the apt package that matches the architecture of your Kali Linux (e.g. amd64). When you click the architecture link it will take you to a download page where you can choose a download mirror that is close to your physical location.

Then install the apt package from the terminal using a command of the form: `sudo dpkg -i <package-name-of-downloaded-apt>`